# jQuery: search for multiple values that are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, sudoku

```
HTML:
<div class="sudoku">
    <div class="tr tr-1">
        <div class="td col-1 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        <div class="td col-2 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        <div class="td col-3 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        ...
        <div class="td col-9 block-3"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr tr-2">
        <div class="td col-1 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        <div class="td col-2 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        <div class="td col-3 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        ...
        <div class="td col-9 block-3"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr tr-3">
        <div class="td col-1 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        <div class="td col-2 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        <div class="td col-3 block-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
        ...
        <div class="td col-9 block-3"><input type="number" min="1" max="9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr tr-4">
    ...
    </div>
...
</div>
```

---

```
JS:
$('.sudoku input').change(function() {
    $('.sudoku input').each( function(index,value) {
        console.log('#' + index + ': ' + $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

I've got a table with 9x9 = 81 input fields (Sudoku).
I want to search/iterate through all of them and check whether two (or more) input fields in any block, row, or column are the same, then mark duplicates with .addClass() and append an error message to a 'div.message'.
The JS is how I get all of the values.
I have tried multiple approaches with the .length of '.sudoku input[value=#]', none of which worked so far.
Can u help me?

Comment: For perfectly tabular scenarios like this, there is absolutely no harm in using tables themselves. :)

Comment: I agree, this would be a little easier with a `<table>`, but what do you want to get as the result of this search? The user enters a number and recieves an alert to tell them the number they used is already entered, or should one of the duplicate values be cleared? Or highlighted?

Comment: instead of using DOM as value grid why don't you internally use array of 9x9 in javascript, that would be fast

Answer (score 3):

I will first add a couple of data attributes for me to easily identify the row and column where the edit happened:

```
<div class="sudoku">
    <div class="tr tr-1" data-row="1">
        <div class="td col-1 block-1" data-column="1">...</div>
        <div class="td col-2 block-1" data-column="2">...</div>
        <div class="td col-3 block-1" data-column="3">...</div>
        ...
        <div class="td col-9 block-3" data-column="9">...</div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

This way, I can easily get the edited row and column by querying the `data-row` or `data-column` of the closest `.tr` or `.td` respectively.

Now, when some cell gets edited, i will look for duplicates only in the row/column where the edit happened (instead of the whole board).

```
$('.sudoku input').change(function() {

    var editedCell = $(this).closest('.td')[0];

    // get the row and col where the edit happened
    var row = $(this).closest('.tr').data('row'),
        col = $(this).closest('.td').data('column'),
        val = $(this).val();

    var hasDups = false;

    // check if any other cells in the same row has same value
    // note: can be made simpler with $(this).siblings().each(...)
    $('.sudoku .tr[data-row='+row+']').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('input').val() === val && this !== editedCell) {
            $(this).addClass('duplicate');
            hasDups = true;
        }
    });

    // check if any other cells in the same col has same value
    $('.sudoku .td[data-col='+col+']').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('input').val() === val && this !== editedCell) {
            $(this).addClass('duplicate');
            hasDups = true;
        }
    });
    if(hasDups) $(this).addClass('duplicate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose something like this would do it:

```
$('.sudoku input').change(function () {
    var values = {};
    var clean = true;
    $('.sudoku input').each(function (index, input) {
        if (values[input.value]) {
            input.classList.add('error');
            clean = false;
        } else values[input.value] = input;
    });
    if (!clean) $('div.message').html('Please... no duplicate values...');
});
```

This way it loops all inputs and adds their value as a `key` in a new object. If the `key` already exists in that object it will instead add the class to the duplicate and change the `clean` flag so the error message will be issued.